# datetime parse in ELK

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to parse log using ELK stack. following is my sample log

```
2015-12-11 12:05:24+0530 [process] INFO: process 0.24.5 started
```

I am using the following grok

```
grok{
    match => {"message" => "(?m)%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:processdate}\s+\[%{WORD:name}\]\s+%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}"}
    }
```

and my elastic search mapping is

```
{
    "properties": {
        "processdate":{
            "type":   "date",
            "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss+SSSS"
        },
        "name":{"type" : "string"},
        "loglevel":{"type" : "string"},
    }
}
```

But while loading into Elastic search i am getting below error,

```
 "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse [processdate]", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"Invalid format: \"2015-12-11 12:05:39+0530\" is malformed at \" 12:05:39+0530\""}}}}, :level=>:warn}
```

How to modify it to a proper data format? I have added the proper date format in elastic search.

**Update:**  localhost:9200/log

```
{"log":{"aliases":{},"mappings":{"filelog":{"properties":{"processdate":{"type":"date","format":"yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ssZ"},"loglevel":{"type":"string"},"name":{"type":"string"}}}},"settings":{"index":{"creation_date":"1458218007417","number_of_shards":"5","number_of_replicas":"1","uuid":"_7ffuioZS7eGBbFCDMk7cw","version":{"created":"2020099"}}},"warmers":{}}}
```

Comment: `S` is for fraction of seconds, try `Z` instead, like `yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ssZ`

Comment: Weird, it works well on my end. Can you update your question with the output you get from `curl -XGET localhost:9200/your_index` ?

Comment: @Val, Updated my question with the index info

Comment: Can you try without the ticks, i.e. simply `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"` both (with and without ticks) work on my end on both ES 1.7 and 2.2

Comment: "reason"=>"Invalid format: \"2015-12-11 17:18:32+0530\" is malformed at \" 17:18:32+0530\""}}}}, :level=>:warn}

Comment: @val I am getting the above error now

Comment: Dumb question, but are you certain that your `elasticsearch` output is correctly configured? Do you mind sharing it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106599/discussion-between-backtrack-and-val).

Comment: I have output the parsed log in console. Following is the ouput "{"@timestamp":"2016-03-17T13:13:00.715Z","@version":"1","path":"/home/57919c919fd11.log","host":"XXXXX.YYYY.local","processdate":"2015-12-11 12:05:39+0530","name":"AAAAAAa","loglevel":"INFO"}"

Comment: That's good, the parsing is ok, but can you show how you configured out `elasticsearch` output plugin in the logstash config?

Comment: Hi @Val   output {elasticsearch {hosts => ["172.16.2.204:9200"] index => "log" } } . Here is my output config

Comment: Ok then you need to add this: `document_type => "logfile"` to your `elasticsearch` config otherwise the default type is `logs` which won't trigger your mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting means that your date format is wrong. Fix your date format like this, i.e. use `Z` (timezone) at the end instead of `+SSSS` (fraction of seconds):

```
{
    "properties": {
        "processdate":{
            "type":   "date",
            "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"
        },
        "name":{"type" : "string"},
        "loglevel":{"type" : "string"}
    }
}
```

Also, according to our earlier exchange, your `elasticsearch` output plugin is missing the `document_type` setting and should be configured like this instead in order to make use of your custom `filelog` mapping type (otherwise the default `logs` type is being used and your custom mapping type is not kicking in):

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["172.16.2.204:9200"] 
        index => "log" 
        document_type => "filelog" 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Oops, my bad, yes. Fixed

Comment: Worked like gem :)

Comment: Awesome, glad we figured it out!